# Is there an easy way to "get" an image's size in PHP without javascript?

Tags: php, image

Say I have the URL of an image, is there an easy way to get it's height/width using PHP?
I'd prefer not to use javascript if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

> The [**getimagesize**()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function will
>   determine the size of any given image
>   file and return the dimensions along
>   with the file type and a height/width
>   text string to be used inside a normal
>   HTML  tag and the correspondant
>   HTTP content type.
>
> Returns an array with 7 elements.
>
> Index 0 and 1 contains respectively
>   the width and the height of the image.

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("yourimage.jpg");
```

---

Also there is [imagesx](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) and [imagesy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php) functions to get width and height of images individually.

Comment: Followup question (or should I ask a seperate question?)
If URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration, and that's not something I can (or want) to change, do I have any options?

Comment: Could you open new question? So you could get more answer from many people.