# PHP: Obtaining Image Size

Tags: php, html, image, server-side

I am writing down a function and it takes an argument which is the physical path of an image on server. I was wondering if it is possible in any way to obtain its original size in pixels.

In one variable I would like to store its width and in other variable its height. The challenge that made me ask this is because I have to obtain it on server-side thus any client-side solution would not help.

Comment: Duplicate of this, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137217/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-an-images-size-in-php-without-javascript

Comment: There really needs to be a way to undo a close vote... Darn foggy morning brain not paying attention to what question it was reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
<?php
    $size = getimagesize ("img.jpg");
    echo "<img src=\"img.jpg\" {$size[3]}>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example will help you to get image height and width parameter in their separate variables like $width and $height.

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('image/testimage.jpg', $info);
echo $width;
echo $height;
```