# PHP: Get the Height and Width of an Image File in a Directory with PHP

Tags: php, jpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Obtaining Image Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964750/php-obtaining-image-size)

I have a directory called **images**, containing - surprise! - images in .jpg format.

Is it possible to determine the width and height of the image with PHP, and output these two values inside the img tag?

How can this be done, if yes?

More specifically, I have this:

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$image = $row['image_directory'] . '/' . $row['image'];`

the `$image` variable now contains returns something like images/image1.jpg.

How can I apply `getimagesize()` function to that variable, receive width and height as two separate variables, and access those variables to output them within html tag?

Comment: Also, feel free to try our [search feature](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20image%20size).

Comment: Thanks! I promise to give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no specific answer that I was looking for, and someone may be looking for similar information sometime in the future, I feel it would be fair if I unswer my own question.

So, I had this code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
  $image = $row['image_directory'] . '/' . $row['image'];
```

To get the image info I need, I ended up using this simple bit of code:

```
$size = getimagesize ($image);
```

And to output the image with the corresponding width and height tags, I used this:

```
echo '<img src="'. $image . '" ' . $size[3] . ' />';
```

I agree that my question and answer can be perceived as duplicates of a couple of questions asked and answered in the past, but small nuances is what's important here. Hope my answer can help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Try `getimagesize()` it will give you the height and width http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Could you please show me, Rob? (Please see the edit in the body of the question.)

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov, there's example code on the manual page.  Go read it.

Comment: There is an example in the link i pasted. We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I would gladly write a code for you if you asked, but I understand that you may be busy, so no problem.