# how can I get the size (height & width) of a image (link) with PHP

Tags: php, html

How can i get the height and width of an image?

As example i have this link here:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK3za.jpg)

how can i get the size of the image with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Image Height and Width as integer values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179100/get-image-height-and-width-as-integer-values)

Comment: see `getimagesize` function.

Comment: this will help http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to "get" an image's size in PHP without javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137217/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-an-images-size-in-php-without-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
This is to find height and width of an image.

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image_name.jpg");
echo "Image width " .$width;
echo "<BR>";
echo "Image height " .$height;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('path');
```

Comment: That is just completely the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179126 just only a code only answer